# Generate WSDL / SOAP specification from C# Interface as client?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl

Here's my situation: I'm writing a SOAP client using WCF.  I am going to invite 3rd parties to develop services that my client can consume.  This is kind of backwards from the norm, I think.  As the client develper, I'm creating the specification, and the server developers are following it.

When it's the other way around, and the server developer is using C#/.NET, the process would go something like:

1) Service developer creates C# interface, a service type that implements it, and a host to serve it.
2) Service developer uses its server to generate WSDL and provides it to client developer.
3) Client developer uses WSDL document to generate a proxy and uses the proxy to consume the service.

However, I'm completely at a loss as to how to do this in reverse.  So far, the only thing I've been able to thing of is to do step 1 as a mock, generate the WSDL for my mock, and provide it to the service developer.  I'd prefer not to have to go through the work of doing this.  Plus, I'm not sure how feasible it is for the service developer to generate a service based on a a WSDL document, especially since the service developers would probably not be using .NET.  They could be using any number of SOAP frameworks and languages.  I'm afraid that their service implementations would end up differing enough that my client application wouldn't be compatible with all of them at the same time.

I want this to be as easy as possible for the service developers, to encourage them to write them, but I want to have a single client, without having to modify my client code for each server.

I'm not really familiar with SOAP frameworks, other than WCF, so I don't really know how much is the same/different from WCF implementation.

Ideally, I'd like to just provide them with the C# interfaces, or run them through some tool that would generate information that they can use to implement their services in their language/framework of choice, and perfectly implement my specification.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you create a sample service for that client instead? Then you can export the WSDL from that service and also have a working example for testing purposes.

Comment: I did already think of that.  I'm just not sure how easy/feasable it is to write a service based on a WSDL document, particularly if it's another language (not .net/wcf).  Are there generally tools available to generate service code stubs from WSDL, like there are for clients?

Comment: 1.  WSDLs are language-agnostic.  It's the WSDL that exposes the service's metadata in a format that (nearly) any language can understand.  2.  A client should not dictate the implementation of the service - the client should consume a WSDL which will tell it everything it needs to know to communicate with the service.  An instance of a client (proxy) is specific to an instance of a service - it sounds almost like you want to make a generic client that communicate with any service.  Can you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Tim, here's an example: Let's say I have an inventory management and order processing application.  I want to be able to communicate with different product manufacturers to get product information (part numbers, costs, etc.).   Since there may be hundreds or thousands of different manufacturers, it wouldn't be feasible to have them each come up with their own WSDL, and for me to write code to consume all of the different data formats.  I need to be able to give them all one format that they can all provide for my one client to consume.

Comment: @JoeMjr2 - Got it.  In that situation I would think the easiest solution would be to simply define what you want your XML to be and tell the various suppliers that you would like them to make their information available via a web service.  As long as their message has the information you required in the format you need, your client should be able to consume and process the response without going to the trouble of generating a complete WSDL that there service needs to produce.

Comment: @JoeMjr2 - Also, if you're actually working on an inventory and order processing or anything else related to supply chain management, take a look at [RosettaNet](http://www.rosettanet.org/) and see if your suppliers will agree to use those standards.  I haven't worked with it in about 11 years, but at the time they have standardized formats for lots of different aspects of supply chain management.